# How can pass parameter using ASIHttpRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello friends I am using `ASIHttpRequest` for pass parameter for `JSON`.

Here is my URL 
http://......

```
{
  "cmscontent": 
    {
          "access_name": "about us"
    }
}
```

How can i pass and get response using `ASIHttpRequest`?

Comment: Use this for Demo Project: https://gist.github.com/pokeb/150447

Comment: yes but how can pass this parameter..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ASIFormDataRequest` to pass data
Example

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"name" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"lastname" forKey:@"last_name"];
[request setFile:@"/Users/Documents/image.jpg" forKey:@"photo"];
```